# スケーリングがうまくいかない

Tags: python

[image: 横軸はデータに振り分けられた番号，縦軸はデータ値]

データ値を最小値0，最大値1になるようにスケーリングしたいのですが以下のコードを使うとうまくいっていないように見えました．（下の図のようになってしまいました）データファイルには12行14列にデータが書いてあります．自分が理想としているグラフは元のグラフの山の形を保ったままのものです．よろしくお願いします．
[image: 正規化したはずのグラフ]

```
scaler=MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(data_del)
data_del2 = scaler.transform(data_del)
ch = np.array(range(1,13))
plt.plot(ch,data_del2[0:12], linestyle='None',marker='o')
```

Comment: 12行14列程度なら、そのまま質問にテキストで提示しても問題無いのでは？ まあ行/列共に半分にしても再現できるなら間引いたデータの方が良さそうですが。プログラムの方も、何をimportしたか、どういう風にデータを読んで格納したかも含めて提示してもらった方が、助言や回答が出やすいと思われます。

Comment: すいませんおっしゃったとおりimportの部分を書き損じていただけでした．ご迷惑をおかけしました．指摘していただいた部分は今後の質問の際に気を付けます．

Comment: ありがとうございました

Comment: 質問はあとからでも修正できるので、より詳しい内容に見直してみてください。また、解決したようであれば **自己回答** として投稿してみてください。